# Restart stopped service, after server restart in java executor framework

Tags: java, server, scheduler, executorservice

I have a service which is running using executor in java.In the main method of that service is as follows

```
 public void method()
 {
    // will get some records from database 

       process records one by one
 }
```

For example in my database I have 100 records , after 49 records processed I stopped my server.When I restart the server again it is running from starting means from 1st record.

Is there any possibility to start the service from 50th record.

Possible solution:

whenever server started need to check in previous iteration how many records processed by looking into the database (by maintaining a flag ).Once I found that records , I can skip those records .

Is there any alternative for this or any framework in java which can handle in a proper manner.Please correct me if my solution is not correct or any better solution is available

**NOTE:Here we don't require any transaction management**

Comment: Well I assume this is all transactional, so upon shutting down the server the running transaction is probably aborted. Wouldn't that rollback all your progress tracking?

Comment: @Gimby No actually here we don't require transaction management

Comment: Then I don't see what any mystical framework can do better than your database and a simple ` and processed=0` addition to the query.

Comment: @Gimby This service should run for every 2 days.So I can't maintain in that flag in same table,so I have to create an another table to maintain .